# redirect to login page in AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, redirect

In my JS code I'm checking for a 403 status code on AJAX response and redirect to login page like this:

```
$.ajax({
 statusCode: {
   403: function() {
      window.location.href = "/login";
   }
 }
});
```

Should I use the full url to my site like the follows:

```
 403: function() {
      window.location.href = "www.mysite/login";
   }
```

Or it's enough to use the relative one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the relative URL should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

would it be faster to try with relative url to see if it's working than posting here ?

I think it will work with relative url